# How do I make main content appear in front of background in middle?

Tags: html, css, positioning

I would like to know how to make main content appear in front of background in the middle of the page below header and above footer.  Like on this site for example.  http://cdn.webfactore.co.uk/web_design_example_551_large.jpg  I am not sure if it deals with heights and widths or anything else.  Help me please.  How do I make main content appear in front of background in middle?

Comment: Do you mean the dog image which is coming out of footer?

Comment: No i mean the whole middle section from below header to above footer in front of background.

Comment: Using your browser's developer tool you can understand how it had been done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick HTML5 skeleton

```
<!doctype html>

<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

  <header>

    <div id="header-wrapper">


    </div> 

  </header>


  <div id="content">



  </div>


  <footer>

    <div id="footer-wrapper">


    </div>

  </footer>


</body>

</html>


html,
body {
  background: #ccc;
  font: 62.5% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;  /* --- Setting body font at 62.5% makes 1.2em equal to 12px --- */
  line-height: 1.7em;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #222;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
header {
  background: #555;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#header-wrapper {
  width: 960px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}
#content {
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  width: 960px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}
footer {
  background: #555;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#footer-wrapper {
  width: 960px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain to me please?

Comment: I've changed my answer and make you HTML5 skeleton basic example, and about explaining...to make this short...content is always on top of body/background and to center the content you just gave it some width in CSS e.g. `width: 960px;` than set `margin: 0 auto;` which means margin left/right is auto which puts content on center and top/bottom margin is 0px.

Comment: Ok. Thank you.  Now is there a way to keep entering content and the content box automatically drops/drags down?

Comment: If I understand well what you're asking...of course, replace Content CSS property height with auto or min-height like so `height: auto;` or `min-height: 600px;` or you can remove the height property completely. I edited aformentioned property in my answer.